# Text gets pushed down by menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want a vertical menu to the left side of my site, but the text is getting pushed down and is not to the side of the menu. Please ignore text in the paragraphs and headers. I am sorry for the poor organization or any small mistakes I have made, This is my first language and I am still learning.

```
    <style>
body
    {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#999
    font: 12px/1.4em Arial,sans-serif;
    }
#wrap
    {
    margin-left: 10px auto;
    background: black;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100px;
    }
#header
    {
    background-color:black;
    color: #fff;
    }
#logo
    {
    float: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height:400px;
    padding: 500px
    }
#navWrap
    {
    height:15pxpx;
    }
#nav ul
    {
    margin: 1px;
    padding:1px;
    }
#nav li
    {
    float:center;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none
    }
#nav li a
    {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
#nav li a:hover
    {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
br.clearLeft
    {
    clear: left;
    }
h1
    {
    color:cyan;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: double 5px;
    }
h2
    {
    color:red;
    }
h3
    {
    color:cyan;
    }
p.2
    {
    color:black;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:left;
    }
p
    {
    color:#DBDBDB;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:left
    right: 500px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="navWrap">
                <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaa" class="smothScroll">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaaaaaaaaaa" class="smothScroll">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" class="smothScroll">link1</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br class="clearLeft"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>  
        <p>lalalallalalalalalallalalala</p>
```

Comment: @Fahad Hasan Thanks that fixed my issue but do you mind telling me hoe to have the text stay at the top of the menu?

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but the text is still at the bottom of the menu. I have the padding big so the menu stretches from top to bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `float` your `#wrap` div to the `left` using the following CSS and that'll solve the issue:

```
#wrap {
     float: left;
}
```

Here's a demo:

```css
body {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#999 font: 12px/1.4em Arial, sans-serif;
}
#wrap {
    margin-left: 10px auto;
    background: black;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100px;
}
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color: #fff;
}
#logo {
    float: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height:400px;
    padding: 500px
}
#navWrap {
    height:15pxpx;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 1px;
    padding:1px;
}
#nav li {
    float:center;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none
}
#nav li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
br.clearLeft {
    clear: left;
}
h1 {
    color:cyan;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: double 5px;
}
h2 {
    color:red;
}
h3 {
    color:cyan;
}
p.2 {
    color:black;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:left;
}
p {
    color:#DBDBDB;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:left right: 500px;
}
#wrap {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="navWrap">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaa" class="smothScroll">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaaaaaaaaaa" class="smothScroll">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" class="smothScroll">link1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br class="clearLeft" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>lalalallalalalalalallalalala</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` on your logo is pushing the text down, and your `line-height` is huge. I would suggest adjusting those two values.

```
#logo {
    float: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height:400px; // pushing it down
    padding: 500px; // pushing it down
}
```

Also, you're setting the height on `#navWrap`, which is also causing your navigation to look weird. Finally, floating your `#wrap` element puts your content in the right place.

Here is a fiddle that resolves your situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/cywb70ds/2/

I adjusted the `padding` and `line-height` on the `#logo` element.